# Running keras predictions with Flask gives error

Tags: python, flask, keras

I have a saved keras model that I'm trying to make predictions with on a server hosted using flask. The input dim of the model is 12 and the output dimension is 8. 
When I make a request to the server to make a prediction, I get an error.

server.py

```
model_path = 'dom-loc.h5'
model = load_model(model_path)



@app.route('/api', methods=['POST', 'GET'])

def predict():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    location = model.predict_classes(np.array(data['dompath']))
    output = location[0]
    print('OUTPUT', output)
    return jsonify(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

request.py

```
url = 'http://localhost:5000/api'


r = requests.post(url, json={'dompath':[[2, 3, 5, 1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 6, 8, 4, 8]]})
print(r.json())
```

error for server.py

```
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_4/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 8), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

error for request.py

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Have you tried, 

> `graph = tf.get_default_graph()`

> `with graph.as_default():`
> `   #predict here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During prediction, you need to get the default graph that was constructed. You can do that with the help of the following snippet.

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
with graph.as_default():
    #predict here
```